# React Google Pie Chart Not Displaying

Tags: reactjs, charts, pie-chart, react-google-charts

I am creating a react web app and I am going to be displaying data using googles charts for react. I have a function displayDataChart() that returns a pie chart with dummy data to test. However, when I boot up the website on local host, the graph isnt there. It is just an empty section tag. The code is below.

```
//DASHBOARD PAGE FILE
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner'
import { getExpenses, reset } from '../features/expenses/expenseSlice'
import ExpenseItem from '../components/ExpenseItem'
import TotalItem from '../components/TotalItem'
import {useState} from 'react'
import {Chart} from 'react-google-charts'

function Dashboard() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
  const {expenses, isLoading, isError, message} = useSelector((state) => state.expenses)
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState(getDate('weekly'))
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('all')
  const d1 = new Date()
  const today = d1.toLocaleDateString()
  const [sortType, setSortType] = useState('none')

  const sortMethods = {
    none: { method: (a, b) => null },
    amountAscending: { method: (a, b) => ((parseFloat(a.amount) > parseFloat(b.amount)) ? 1 : -1)  },
    amountDescending: { method: (a, b) => ((parseFloat(a.amount) < parseFloat(b.amount)) ? 1 :-1) },
    dateAscending: { method: (a, b) => ((a.date > b.date) ? 1 : -1)  },
    dateDescending: { method: (a, b) => ((a.date < b.date) ? 1 :-1) }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(isError){
      console.log(message);
    }

    if(!user){
      navigate('/login')
    }
    else(

      dispatch(getExpenses([dateRange[0], dateRange[1] ,category]))
    )

    return () => {
      dispatch(reset())
    }
   
    }, [user, navigate, isError, message, dispatch]
  )

  if(isLoading){
    return <Spinner />
  }

  function displayDataChart(){
    return <section className='content'>
      <Chart
        chartType="PieChart"
        data={[
          ["Task", "Hours per Day"],
          ["Work", 11],
          ["Eat", 2],
          ["Commute", 2],
          ["Watch TV", 2],
          ["Sleep", 7]
        ]}
        options={{
          title: "My Daily Activities",
        }}
        width={"100px"}
        height={"100px"}
      />
    </section>
  }
  
  function displayTotal(totalVal){
    if(expenses.length > 0){
      return <section className='content'>
      <TotalItem total={totalVal}/>
      </section>
    }
  }

  function getTotal(){
    let total = 0
    {expenses.map((expense) =>(
      total += parseFloat(expense.amount)
    ))}
    return total
  }

  function displaysExpenses(){
    return <section className="content">
    {expenses.length > 0 ? (
      <div className="expenses">
        {expenses.map((expense) =>(
          <ExpenseItem key={expense._id} expense ={expense}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    ) : (<h3>No expenses have been added</h3>)}
  </section>
  }

  const getDaysInMonth = (year, month) => new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()

  const addMonths = (input, months) => {
    const date = new Date(input)
    date.setDate(1)
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months)
    date.setDate(Math.min(input.getDate(), getDaysInMonth(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1)))
    const res = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1)
    return res.toLocaleDateString()
  }

  function formatDate(date){
    const split = date.split('/')
    let year = split[2].toString()
    let month = split[0].toString()
    let day = split[1].toString()

    if (split[0].length < 2){
      month = '0' + month
    }

    if (split[1].length < 2){
      day = '0' + day
    }

    return year + '-' + month + '-' + day
  }
  
  function getToday() {
    const today = new Date()
    const tomorrow = new Date(today)
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)
    return[formatDate(today.toLocaleDateString()), formatDate(tomorrow.toLocaleDateString())]
  }
  
  function getMonday(d){
    const dt = new Date(d)
    const day = dt.getDay()
    const diff = dt.getDate() - day + (day === 0 ? -6 : 1);
    return new Date(dt.setDate(diff)).toLocaleDateString()
  }

  function getSunday(d){
    var date = new Date(d);
    if (date.getDay() === 0) {
        return date.toLocaleDateString()
    }
    else{
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + (0 - 1 - date.getDay() + 7) % 7 + 1);
        return date.toLocaleDateString()
    }
}

function getWeekly(d) {
  return [formatDate(getMonday(d)), formatDate(getSunday(d))]
}

function getMonthly(d) {
  const date = new Date(d);
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1)
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0)
  return [formatDate(firstDay.toLocaleDateString()), formatDate(lastDay.toLocaleDateString())]
}

function getPast6Months(d){
  return [formatDate(addMonths(d, -6)), formatDate(d.toLocaleDateString())]
}

function getYearly(d){
  return [formatDate(addMonths(d, -12)), formatDate(d.toLocaleDateString())]
}

 function getDate(type){
    const todaysDate = new Date()
    let returnDate = new Date()

    switch(type){
      case "today":
        return getToday()
      case "weekly":
        return getWeekly(todaysDate)
      case "monthly":
        return getMonthly(todaysDate)
      case "6 months":
        return getPast6Months(todaysDate)
      case "yearly":
        return getYearly(todaysDate)
      case "all time":
        return "2000-01-01"
    }
  }


  return(
    <>
    <section className='heading'>
      <h1>{user && user.firstName + " " + user.lastName}'s Dashboard </h1>
    </section>

    <section className='form'>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <label htmlFor='dateRange'>See Expenses From</label>
        <select type='text' name='dateRange' id='dateRange' value={dateRange} onChange={(e) => {setDateRange(e.target.value); dispatch(getExpenses([e.target.value.split(',')[0], e.target.value.split(',')[1], category]))}} >
          <option value={getDate("weekly")}>This Week</option>
          <option value={getDate("today")}>Today</option>
          <option value={getDate("monthly")}>This Month</option>
          <option value={getDate("6 months")}>Past 6 months</option>
          <option value={getDate("yearly")}>This year</option>
          <option value={getDate("all time")}>All Time</option>
        </select>
        
        <label htmlFor='category'>Filter By Category</label>
        <select type='text' name='category' id='category' value={category} onChange={(e) => {setCategory(e.target.value); dispatch(getExpenses([dateRange.split(',')[0], dateRange.split(',')[1], e.target.value]))}} >
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="Food">Food</option>
            <option value="Rent">Rent</option>
            <option value="Utilities">Utilities</option>
            <option value="Subcription">Subscription</option>
            <option value="Payment to another entity">Payment to another entity</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>

        <label htmlFor='sortType'>Sort By</label>
        <select type='text' name='sortType' id='sortType' value={sortType} onChange={(e) => {setSortType(e.target.value)}} >
            <option value="none">None</option>
            <option value="dateDescending">Date: Newest to Oldest</option>
            <option value="dateAscending">Date: Oldest to Newest</option>
            <option value="amountDescending">Amount: High to Low</option>
            <option value="amountAscending">Amount: Low to High</option>
          
          </select>
      </div>

    </section>

    {displayTotal(getTotal())}
    {displaysExpenses()}
    {displayDataChart()}

 
    </>
)
}

export default Dashboard
```

In the image attached you can see that the graph is not displaying and in the inspect elements tab, the last section tag (with className as content) is empty. I cant get the graph to render at all.

[image: Screenshot]